# Using If-Let and checking the output in a single line

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

This is just an example to illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

I want to check if an optional contains a value and if it is greater than 0. I currently have it this way:

```
if let value = Double(textFieldText) {
  if value > 0 {
    return true
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in a single line? Something like:

```
if let value = Double(textFieldText) && value > 0{
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `where` clause:

```
if let value = Double(textFieldText) where value > 0 {
```

Another option using [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72):

```
if Double(textFieldText) ?? -Double.infinity > 0 {
```

Thanks to comments below which help me realize `nil > 0` doesn't throw an error:

```
if Double(textFieldText) > 0 {
```

is by far the simplest option.

Comment: :-) finally if Double(textFieldText) > 0 { (as mentioned by Doug ) is the simplest and cleanest ...

Comment: Yeah, Double(textFieldText) returns `nil` for unconvertible strings so comparing like `nil > 0` seemed vague to me so I used nil coalescing operator because `nil ?? DBL_MIN` would always return DBL_MIN.

Comment: try this let str2 = "A";
       Double(str2) ?? DBL_MIN > 0 // true

Comment: nil in Swift doesn't represent reference as in Objective C. nil is value which means nothing, or not available. Swift's Optional is an enum (value type)

Comment: It seems I misunderstood *precedence* for operators. According to this http://nshipster.com/swift-operators/ the comparison operator `<` have higher precedence than nil coal. op. `??`. Then shouldn't "DBL_MIN > 0" (-> `nil`) be evaluated first, and only after that does expression `Double(..) ?? nil` evaluate? I've tested and this seems to not be the case (hence the `>0` is associated with the *result* of `Double(..) ?? DBL_MIN`), but what am I missing here?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems the link I posted to contains (nowadays) faulty information! The precedence of `??` is listed as `100` in linked post, but if we look in Swift 2 (cmd-click `import Swift`) it's now of precedence `131`. Hence, precedent over the comparison operator `<` which has precedence `130`! So my logic wasn't at a fault here, but my precedence value for the nil coalescing operator was :)

Comment: @dfri import Foundation;
Double("A") ?? DBL_MIN > 0 // true;
Double(1) ?? DBL_MIN > 0   // true;
Double(-1) ?? DBL_MIN > 0  // false;
Double(0) ?? DBL_MIN > 0   // false

Comment: nil < 0  // true;
nil == 0 // false;
nil > 0  // false;
nil < "A" // true;
nil == "A"// false;
nil > "A" // false; generally this is not very smart use of nil in Swift

Comment: @user3441734 I agree. The most important point your brought up, however, is that `DBL_MIN > 0 // true`, so this was a real issue. Using `-Double.infinity` (or why not just `-1`?) solved that issue, however.

Answer (score 6):

### Solution in 1 line

I think the simplest way to write your logic is this

```
return Double(textFieldText) > 0
```

### Test

```
func foo(textFieldText:String) -> Bool {
    return Double(textFieldText) > 0
}

foo("1") // true
foo("-1") // false
foo("a") // false
foo("0") // false
foo("123a") // false
```

### Why does this work?

When 2 values are compared in Swift and (exactly) one of them is `nil`, then `nil` is always less than the other value.

So every time the initialiser of `Double` does fail, like here

```
return Double("a") > 0
```

the expression becomes

```
return nil > 0
```

which is `false`.

The only way the expression does return `true` is when the input string is parsed as a `Double` value which is actually greater then `0`.
Which is exactly the logic you where looking for :)

Comment: nice explanation! strictly speaking, nil is literal. all optionals conforms to NilLiteralConvertible protocol, that means we can assign nil to any optional. but we can compare only optionals of the same type. let d = Optional<Double>.None; let i = Optional<Int>.None; d == nil // true; i == nil // true; d == i // error! (even though both values are nil)

Comment: @user3441734: Very important addition to my explanation. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

With a where clause:

```
if let value = Double(textFieldText) where value > 0 {
    return true
}
```

Or simply:

```
if Double(textFieldText) > 0 {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Any cons and pros between those two options? Or are them just the same?

Comment: @Marcelo in the first case the unwrapped value can be use inside {} block.

Comment: @Marcelo by the way, guard let value = Double(str) where value > 0 else { return };
print(value); could be better solution sometimes

Answer (score 2):

One more way you can do the same thing and that would steer you away from ugly if let nesting.

```
   func hello(values:String) -> Bool {
      guard let value = Double(values) where value > 0 else {
         return false
      }     
      return true
   }
```

Comment: you can use where in guard statement as well. guard let value = Double(str) where value > 0 else { return }. Double("something") will NOT throw any error, it returns Optional<Double>.None value which can be represented by literal nil

Comment: Yup I know that, but I made it this way to return a Boolean value. The reason I put it in a guard value was in case that value has to be a double. If it has to be double then you don't want it to be a nil value.

Comment: once again Double("something") doesn't throw, it returns nil. it is clear now?

Comment: I do understand that. I was just trying to separate the different conditions that the result would be false. If value cannot be converted to double or if value is not greater than 0.

Comment: do you really understand, what do / try / check is for? what did you do actually can be rewritten as func hello2(myText:String) -> Bool {
        let value = Double(myText)
        if value > 0 {
            return true
        }
    return false
}

Comment: Oops I was looking at the wrong function. My mistake. Yes that function doesn't throw. I will edit it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if let value = textFieldText as? Double where value > 0 {
  return true
}
```

Comment: textFieldText as? Double will ALWAYS results wit nil (except textFieldText is Double) Before answer, try you idea first, please.

Comment: Since the original question had a double, I went with the question and type casted it to double. It makes sense when you dont have a double, it will return nil, for sure.

Comment: try this    let txt = "1";  if let d = txt as? Double { print("WILL NEVER PRINT THIS") } else { print("WILL ALWAYS PRINT THIS") }; It will ALWAYS print WILL ALWAYS PRINT THIS

Comment: result of optional casting from any type to Double is nil, except you cast Double as? Double, which gives you Double? (Optional<Double>). if textFieldText represents string "1" or "100,5" or "3.14" or "alpha" or .... your example will NEVER return true. where value > 0 or where value == 0 or where value < 0, all where clauses are redundant, because value will ALWAYS be nil. Casting and conversion (aka Double(textFieldText)) are different tasks

Comment: see that even though you will try to cast Float(3.14) as? Double , the result will be nil.

Comment: Got you. Only thing I was doing wrong was I was taking a string and expecting it to be Double. However, I did a work around on this. Consider the following statements.

func functionCheck ()  {
  if let value = Double("1") where value > 0 {
    print("success")
  } else {
    print("failure")
  }
}
The only problem I am thinking is even if I pass "1" as integer, still above code successfully gives me success message.

Comment: ... if I pass "1" as integer ... that is your misunderstanding. "1" is String and Double("1") calls Double.init?(_ text: String) which returns optional Double value or nil, if conversion is non successful